# How to hide the source code on inspecting

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to avoid inspecting my page and i am working in mvc .net.I have tried with some jquerys ,but not working.

Comment: use flash or silverlight

Answer (score 3):

You can try following methods:

123 is keyCode of `f12` key which prevent from open Inspect Element screen in browser. On keyDown return false that does not open Inspect Element screen.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==123){
    return false;
   }
else if(event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode==73){        
      return false;  //Prevent from ctrl+shift+i
   }
});
```

Prevent from Right Click Inspect Element

```
$(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){        
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

But this cannot be completely applied to a web page.

Even if you disable right click and disable the default behaviors for `F12`, `Ctrl+Shift+I`, and `Ctrl+Shift+J`, there is no way to stop a user from opening Dev Tools on a different page and navigating to your page with Dev Tools already open.

Also, you can access Dev Tools by going to `Menu > Tools > Developer` tools, which cannot be prevented by any website.